# Erro ImageView Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, apple

Fala galera...

Estou desenvolvendo um app, mas está com um erro de optional (acredito que seja esse o erro), tenho o seguinte cenário:  Um botão "A" e um "B" em uma ViewController(1) principal ao clicar no botão "A" teria que abrir uma segunda ViewController(2) com a imagem "X" e ao clicar no Botão "B" abrir a mesma ViewController(2) porém carregando a imagem "Y".  Se não seto nenhuma imagem, a ViewController(2) abre normalmente.

Sintaxe para carregar a imagem creio estar correta:

```
@IBOutlet weak var fundo: UIImageView!
@IBAction func botaAcao(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagem = UIImage(named: "imagem1.jpg")!
        fundo.image = imagem

    }
```

pois ao colocar uma ImageView no ViewController(1) principal a imagem carrega normalmente, porém ao tentar abrir  no segundo ViewController(2) não.

Da o seguinte erro:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala, Rodrigo, beleza?

Bom pelo tempo que já faz a pergunta, tu já deve ter resolvido.

Mas, apenas para documentar pra outros devs, vou deixar a solução aqui:

Se a imagem não funciona apenas no ViewController(2), muito provavelmente é porque o atributo "fundo" não foi linkado ao elemento no Storyboard.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Blz Alberto. Obrigado pelo comentário, já consegui resolver. Na verdade estava linkado certinho. Eu resolvi usando segue, como eu tinha vários botões e para cada botão um fundo diferente se abriria, o melhor foi usar dessa forma...

if segue.identifier == "botao1"{
             let vcDestination = segue.destination as! NewViewController
            vcDestination.imgBotao = 1

Mas obrigado...